# Can't find table name in Yii

Tags: yii

Yii give a error in my local host

> The table "house_user" for active record class "User" cannot be found
>   in the database

online

```
throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','The table "{table}" for active record class "{class}" cannot be found in the database.',
```

but house user exist in the database

Comment: Test your database connection. Check for typos. Table names case sensitive so be aware.

Comment: check model User and name in that for the function tableName

Comment: Can you please show the Database Structure and can you also post the house_user model class please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check some steps :

1- check your connection to database if true on

```
protected\config
```

2- check your database if it's true

3- check model , in model you need to check table name and all columns

4- Check capital and small latter in model because Linux server is case sensitive

If all steps not worked then add new model using Yii Gii .